# Label is ambiguous imported from the namespaces

Tags: asp.net

I add ext.net to my existing project with Nugget but now I have this error in

```
    Error   193 'Label' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types
 'System.Web.UI.WebControls, Ext.Net'.
```

i don't want to import`System.Web.UI.WebControls` in all my page. is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
i remove 
 `<add namespace="Ext.Net" />` from web.config and add: `using Ext.Net` to every page that i need. so i didn't rename anything in my project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a second class named Label. You either have to refer to that other class with its fully qualified name, or use System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label to refer to the second Label type.. If it's your own class you can consider renaming it to something other than Label.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i Have more than 1000 like this in my project i can't change all of theme!

Comment: In Visual Studio you can attempt a global search and replace